# Postman script - Calculate sum and return the value to 2 decimal places

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-testcase

In a Postman test script, I am trying to get a specific value using a simple calculation and return that value, in order to use it in a subsequent parts of the request.

```js
let expectedDpay = temp.payPlanPremiumAmount;
let expectedDpay = (expectedDpay*12.5)/100;
```

The expected value I get is, for example `136.125` but I would like it to return to 2 decimal places, `136.13`.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: What is the value of `expectedDpay` that's times by 12.5?

Comment: `expectedDpay = Math.round((expectedDpay*12.5)/100).toFixed(2)` ?

Comment: @DannyDainton, close :) - that will round to an integer *first*, then apply the two decimal places (eg. resulting in `136.00`). OP wants it "colloquially rounded" to 2 decimal places.

Comment: That was a guess, I didn't actually try it  - That's why I left it as a comment 

Answer (score 1):

Try [`num.toFixed(2)`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp) to round to 2 decimal places.

```
expectedDPay = ((expectedDPay * 12.5)/100).toFixed(2);
```